# Get total webpage size and load time from WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

How would i get total webpage size (html + images + js + extra) from a page loaded in a webview? And how would i get the total load time of the page?

I can use `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` to track the page load process, but I'm not sure if the time between them is only for the htl part, or if it contains all the time to load the resources (jpegs, .css, .js, etc).

And how would I get (if possible) the total page size?

I need to do this in an app, so connecting it to the PC doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For determine time you can use onPageStarted and onPageFinished method

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
        start = (new Date()).getTime;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        end = (new Date()).getTime;
    total time=end-start;
    }
});
```

and to determine length of webpage you can use URLConnection

```
URL url = new URL("url");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```